# Is it possible to use @ContentChild and @ContentChildren for projected DOM elements?

Tags: angular

Assuming the content projection:

```
  <app-page>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </app-page>
```

Can I be able to mutate the h1 in app-page component through @ContentChild?

So far (after `<ng-content>` in the app-page), I have checked `@ContentChild('h1', {static: true}) header;` in the ngAfterContentInit(). It is `undefined`.

On the other hand, if the projected content were to be a component, `@ContentChild(DummyComponent) content;`, it is properly initialized.

I also read in the documentation:

> Does not retrieve elements or directives that are in other components' templates, since a component's template is always a black box to its ancestors.

My question is, can a component mutate the native elements in the projected content in any way?

Comment: It shows `undefined` because `h1`  is neither a **component**, **directive** or a **template reference**. It should work if you do `<h1 #header>...</h1>` and `@ContentChild(`header`, ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to access element bcoz you have not assigned template refrence varibale

**app.component.ts**

```
<app-page>
    <h1 #ref>Hello</h1>
 </app-page>
```

**app.page.component.ts**

```
@ContentChild("h1") header: ElementRef;
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/content-child-children-qjsmyf)